Bogoliubov de Gennes formalism for rotating systems
I have a question relating to the Bogoliubov de Gennes formalism. I am studying Bose Einstein condensates and I want to calculate the excitation energies of a system in one dimension (a ring with periodic boundary conditions) and two components. Therefore I calculate the groundstate via imaginary time propagation. This works fine. In the next step I want to calculate the excitations so I expand the wavefunction linear in a perturbation $\lambda$ and keep all terms up to first order in $\lambda$. My ansatz looks like this:
$$\Psi_i(x,t)=\Psi_{0,i}(x)e^{-i\mu_i t}+u_i(x)e^{-i\omega t-i\mu_i t}-v_i(x)^*e^{i\omega^* t-i\mu_i t}\,\, .$$
I use the BdG matrix from this paper (http://brunojulia.fqa.ub.edu/works/Morera%20Navarro%20Iv%C3%A1n.pdf). I know the chemical potential $\mu_i$. After the imaginary time propagation I have the wavefunction as a discret list but I exapnd it in plane waves to obtain a continous function. I use the mathematica command "NDEigensystem" to get the eigenvalues $\omega$ and the eigenfunctions $u_i,v_i$. Everything works fine for the static case.
Now I want to include rotation to the system. I calculate the wavefunction in the rotating frame (this works) and I have adjusted the BdG matrix elements. My problem is that my eigenvalues become imaginary as soon as I start to rotate the system. I am asking myself if I made a mistake in my BdG formalism or if it is not making sense what I am doing. I know that complex eigenvalues are a feature of an instable groundstate, but I know that my imaginary time propation works, so I either have a mistake in my formalism or I am doing something which makes no sense. I havent found any literaure on this.
I add the following matrix to the matrix from the paper above:
\begin{pmatrix}
-\Omega \hat{L}  & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \Omega \hat{L}^* & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -\Omega \hat{L} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \Omega \hat{L}^* 
\end{pmatrix}
Here $\Omega$ is the rotation that I apply to my system and $\hat{L}=i\hbar \partial / \partial \phi$ is my angular momentum operator. I also adjust my chemical potential. I obtain it by
$$\mu_i = \frac{1}{N_i}(E_{kin,i}+E_{int,i}-\Omega L_i)\,\, .$$
(So integrate the stationary Gross Pitaeski equation over the whole space after multplying by $\Psi^*$.) I calculate the angular momentum $L$ from the ground state wavefunction.
I would be very thankful for any help regarding literature or advices. Thank you a lot

Can one rotate bose condensate without it being charged and the presence of a magnetic field? ${\bf v} = \nabla \phi$ requires $\omega\equiv  {\rm curl}{\bf  v}=0$ but a rotating fluid requires $\omega= 2\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the angular velocity.  A rotating superconductor generates it own magnetic field.

Yes, that is defintly possible. The presence of vortices in BEC is well studdied. My question is more about the excitations of such a vortex state.

Yes, but the rigidly rotating system has higher energy than the vortex threaded system and is unstable to vortices nucleating at the the boundaries. Are you trying to solve the BdG equations for systems with a vortex array?  I find that one vortex is hard enough!

There is much study of modes in interacting vortex arrays. Have you read Gordon Baym's https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0308342?

I would like to solve the BdG equations numerically. Since I work in one Dimension (which is a ring in the case of periodic boundary conditions) there is no vortex lattice possible. There is one votex in the center of the ring, but the only thing that shows the presence of the vortex is the phase (which is not constant anymore for a vortex).

OK sounds a viable scheme. I'll think about the complex ev's
